# Give an example of a function that is not strictly increasing. Draw its graph and prove that the function is not strictly increasing

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I picked x^4 to be a function which is not strictly increasing for all real numbers.

Since  to be not strictly increasing means that for the function y=f(x)

x1 < x2 then f(x1)< f(x2)

but I get stuck, Im not sure how to go about proving this.

Comment: Why work so hard? Any constant function (e.g., $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$) will work. You just have to show that there is at least one pair of real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1<x_2$, but $f(x_1)\not<f(x_2)$, i.e., $f(x_1)\ge f(x_2)$.

Comment: What you seem to think the meaning of «$f$ is not strictly increasing» is, is not quite correct.

Comment: Strictly increasing means exactly what it says, for every x,y in the domain of f where y > x, then f(y) > f(x). No equality allowed.I corrected the OPs definition. You're welcome.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 You corrected the post and it still reads `Since to be not strictly increasing means that for the function y=f(x) x1 < x2 then f(x1)< f(x2)`? Well, not sure congrats are in order...

Answer (score 2):

Ok,f(x) = x sin(1/x) on **R** will do nicely and geometrically.

[image]

The function osillates wildly and obviously cannot be strictly increasing.A rigorous proof is easy,you can almost do it from the picture.

Comment: Uh-what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: 1) I think you meant $f(x)=x \sin(1/x)$.  2) This is needlessly complicated.

Comment: You're right,my bad. Fixed.

Comment: But why so complicated?  Why not $f(x)=\sin(x)$?  Or $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Anyway, I took away the -1. =)

Comment: Because this makes me look smarter.........lol Seriously,though-it's not really that complicated. If i really wanted overkill,I could have used the Weirstrauss continuous everywhere and differentiable nowhere function.

Comment: Hahah.  Funny.  lol. +1.